# Angular2 fire has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.4",
    ....//others


    "firebase": "^4.5.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.0",
},

 "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": ">=2.3.1"
 },



 "devDependencies": {
  ..others
 "typescript": "~2.3.3",
 "webpack": "^3.6.0"
}
```

ow in my app module

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "value",
   authDomain: "value",
   databaseURL: "value",
   projectId: "value",
   storageBucket: "value",
   messagingSenderId: "value"
};

"imports:[
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig), AngularFireDatabaseModule

]
```

And in my components where am listening for data channges

```
import {AngularFireDatabase , FirebaseListObservable} from "angularfire2/database";


export class TrackingCenterComponent implements OnInit {
  registered: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

 constructor(
    private _af: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
    this.registered = _af.list('/trucks');
   }

 onSave(){
    this.registered.push({
        truckid: val,truckno:truckno, ..........
      });

  }



}
```

whenever i try compiling with `nppm start` or `ng serve` am getting an error

```
Module '"/home/geowan/Desktop/apps/angular2/bcl/node_modules
/angularfire2/database/index"' has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'.
```

I have no idea why and last week this was working perfectly. What could be wrong. This error started popping up afterupdating my npm packages

What else do i need to change for this to work.

NB: i installed firebase via `npm install firebase angularfire2@next --save`

Comment: Also having same issue.

Comment: @SudiptaDhara ive figued out where the problem is, Recently angular2 fire was upgraded and FirebaseListObservable has now been changed to AngularFireList https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md

Comment: They really messed me up since i had to change in every component where i had used it.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI You should post your solve as an answer so that this question can be marked complete.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your dependancy in app component as follow:

```
`import {AngularFireDatabase , FirebaseListObservable} from "angularfire2/database";`
```

to

```
`import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';`
```

It will work.