# error in Angular - firebase based chat Application

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am creating a chat application by using **Angular 6 and Firebase**, and I am facing following errors:

***Error 1 -***

I am getting error in importing **FirebaseListObservable** from `angularfire2/database`

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
```

> [ts] Module '"/Users/user/Projects/A4/chat-app/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"' has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'.

***Error  - 2***

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '{ query: { limitToLast: number; orderByKey: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'query' does not exist in type 'QueryFn'.

```
getMessages(): FirebaseListObservable<ChatMessage[]> {

return this.db.list('messages', {
  query: {
    limitToLast: 25,
    orderByKey: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chack [Angular2 fire has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564755/angular2-fire-has-no-exported-member-firebaselistobservable)

You need to change your dependancy in app component as follow:

```
`import {AngularFireDatabase , FirebaseListObservable} from "angularfire2/database";`
```

to

```
`import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';`
```

It will work.